# Selecting users with biopsies in a given country for charting

Tags: ruby, database, active-record

I have this monstrosity

```
    @nation_biopsy =  
       User.all.where(country: @nation).group_by{ |u| [u.institute_type, u.biopsy] }
      .map{ |i, o| ["name" => i[0], "y" => User.where(id: o.map(&:id))
      .sum("biopsy")]}.flatten.to_json
```

What it is doing is finding all the users in my database that belong to a country (@nation) and grouping them according to their "institute_type" and then "biopsy" (both columns for users). Then it is trying to convert it to an array of JSON objects for a "Highcharts" script. It works, but as a newbie I am sure this is very database heavy. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm more concerned that all this information is in a single `User` table. Tell us more about your database schema?

Comment: The User has 10 attributes. I'm not sure what you're saying. There are only 3 attributes cited above....biopsy, institute_type and country

Comment: This snippet belongs to a model or a controller?

Comment: This is really interesting, look forward to seeing a rewrite.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes on your code:

- `User.all.where` -> `User.where`.
- The moment you write `group_by` you are not using SQL anymore, performance will suffer.
- The line starting with `sum` is very confusing, the indentation make you think it's the continuation of `map` but in fact it's part of its inner expression. Indentation should reflect the structure of an expression.
- `map` + `flatten` -> `flat_map`.
- `|pair, something|` and then `pair[0]`. You can de-structure arrays using the syntax `|(k, v), something|`.

On a first refactor, I'd write:

```
@nation_biopsy = User
  .where(country: @nation)
  .group_by { |u| [u.institute_type, u.biopsy] }
  .flat_map do |(institute_type, biopsy), users| 
    ["name" => institute_type, "y" => User.where(id: users.map(&:id)).sum("biopsy")]
  end.to_json
```

On a second refactor, I'd try to make it work with SQL. Something like this:

```
@nation_biopsy = User
  .where(country: @nation)
  .group(:institute_type, :biopsy)
  .select(:institute_type, "SUM(biopsy) AS biopsy_count")
  .flat_map { |group| ["name" => group.institute_type, "y" => group.biopsy_count] }
  .to_json
```

Now, if you want to write something fancy use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), it allows you to write it without SQL fragments, which looks kind of cool:

```
users = User.arel_table
@nation_biopsy = User
  .where(users[:country].eq(@nation))
  .group(users[:institute_type], users[:biopsy])
  .select(users[:institute_type], users[:biopsy].sum.as("biopsy_count"))
  .flat_map { ["name" => group.institute_type, "y" => group.biopsy_count] }
  .to_json
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives                                                             [{"name":"Non-university hospital","y":3},{"name":"Non-university hospital","y":5},{"name":"Non-university hospital","y":16},{"name":"Non-university hospital","y":13},{"name":"University hospital","y":1}]      .............in other words its not grouping on institution type

Comment: I don't see how "name" and "y" can  end up being merged in a single hash with my code.

Comment: I just cracked it for what I needed using your code as the start, middle and almost the end. I learned a lot from reading around your code. Many thanks.

Comment: There are two missing brackets in the flat_maps.

Comment: @Daniel, `[:a => 1, :b => 2]`is valid Ruby, inside an array they are optional.

Comment: But there's the opening curly bracket and not the closing one. Is that OK?

Comment: oops, that's not ok :) fixed

Answer (score 0):

My variant of refactor is similar:

```
@nation_biopsy =  
  User.where(country: @nation)
      .group(:institute_type, :biopsy)
      .map{ |(inst, biopsy), users| ["name" => inst, "y" => users.sum(&:biopsy)]}
      .flatten
      .to_json
```

Comment: Does this work? the output of `QueryMethods#group` is completely different than a `Enumerable#group_by`, I am not sure you can do that.